# Scraping with BeautifulSoup for text -- NoneType error

Tags: python, web-scraping, wikipedia

I am trying to get table data from wikipedia but I keep getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request



wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_United_States_Senators"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

name = ""
party = ""
state = ""
picture = ""
link = ""
district = ""

table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })

f = open('output.csv', 'w')

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")


    state = cells[0].find(text=True)
    picture = cells[2].findAll(text=True)
    name = cells[3].find(text=True)
    party = cells[4].find(text=True)


    write_to_file = name + "," + state + "," + party + "," + link + "," + picture + "," + district + "\n"
    print (write_to_file)
    f.write(write_to_file)

f.close()
```

Any help, even another way to do it (thought about using the wiki api but I'm rather lost on what to use), would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are facing is that `soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })` returns `None`. There is an element of class `sortable wikitable sortable`, though, and maybe you want that element.

I fixed that and added an `if` and a few `print`s. It still doesn't work, but the problem is easier to fix, I guess. Now it's your turn :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request

wiki =  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_United_States_Senators"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(wiki)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

name = ""
party = ""
state = ""
picture = ""
link = ""
district = ""

table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "sortable wikitable sortable" })

f = open('output.csv', 'w')

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    if cells:
        state = cells[0].find(text=True)
        picture = cells[2].findAll(text=True)
        name = cells[3].find(text=True)
        party = cells[4].find(text=True)

        print(state, type(state))
        print(picture, type(picture))
        print(name, type(name))
        print(party, type(party))
        write_to_file = name + "," + state + "," + party + "," + link + "," + picture + "," + district + "\n"
        print (write_to_file)
        f.write(write_to_file)
        f.flush()

f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it to work (with the text anyways) but I am still trying to figure out how to get the picture links.

Comment: I tried using something like "picture = cells.findAll("a")" but it returns a result set. How would I just get the link? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4, requests

base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_United_States_Senators'
response = requests.get(base_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

with open('out.txt', 'w', newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for row in table('tr'):
        row_text = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row('td') if td.text ]
        writer.writerow(row_text)
        print(row_text)
```

print:

```
[]
['Alabama', '3', 'Shelby, RichardRichard Shelby', 'Republican', 'None', 'U.S. House,Alabama Senate', 'University of Alabama, Tuscaloosa(BA;LLB)Birmingham School of Law(JD)', 'January 3, 1987', '(1934-05-06)May 6, 1934(age\xa082)', '2022']
['Alabama', '2', 'Sessions, JeffJeff Sessions', 'Republican', 'Lawyer in private practice', 'Alabama Attorney General,U.S. Attorneyfor theSouthern District of Alabama', 'Huntingdon College(BA)University of Alabama, Tuscaloosa(JD)', 'January 3, 1997', '(1946-12-24)December 24, 1946(age\xa069)', '2020']
['Alaska', '3', 'Murkowski, LisaLisa Murkowski', 'Republican', 'Lawyer in private practice', 'Alaska House', 'Georgetown University(BA)Willamette University(JD)', 'December 20, 2002', '(1957-05-22)May 22, 1957(age\xa059)', '2022']
['Alaska', '2', 'Sullivan, DanDan Sullivan', 'Republican', 'Lawyer in private practice', 'Alaska Natural Resources Commissioner,Alaska Attorney General,U.S. Assistant Secretary of State for Economic and Business Affairs', 'Harvard University(BA)Georgetown University(MS;JD)', 'January 3, 2015', '(1964-11-13)November 13, 1964(age\xa052)', '2020']
```

out.txt:

```
Alabama,3,"Shelby, RichardRichard Shelby",Republican,None,"U.S. House,Alabama Senate","University of Alabama, Tuscaloosa(BA;LLB)Birmingham School of Law(JD)","January 3, 1987","(1934-05-06)May 6, 1934(age 82)",2022
Alabama,2,"Sessions, JeffJeff Sessions",Republican,Lawyer in private practice,"Alabama Attorney General,U.S. Attorneyfor theSouthern District of Alabama","Huntingdon College(BA)University of Alabama, Tuscaloosa(JD)","January 3, 1997","(1946-12-24)December 24, 1946(age 69)",2020
Alaska,3,"Murkowski, LisaLisa Murkowski",Republican,Lawyer in private practice,Alaska House,Georgetown University(BA)Willamette University(JD),"December 20, 2002","(1957-05-22)May 22, 1957(age 59)",2022
Alaska,2,"Sullivan, DanDan Sullivan",Republican,Lawyer in private practice,"Alaska Natural Resources Commissioner,Alaska Attorney General,U.S. Assistant Secretary of State for Economic and Business Affairs",Harvard University(BA)Georgetown University(MS;JD),"January 3, 2015","(1964-11-13)November 13, 1964(age 52)",2020
Arizona,3,"McCain, JohnJohn McCain",Republican,None,"U.S. House,U.S. NavyCaptain",United States Naval Academy(BS),"January 3, 1987","(1936-08-29)August 29, 1936(age 80)",2022
Arizona,1,"Flake, JeffJeff Flake",Republican,Nonprofit director,U.S. House,"Brigham Young University, Utah(BA;MA)","January 3, 2013","(1962-12-31)December 31, 1962(age 53)",2018
Arkansas,3,"Boozman, JohnJohn Boozman",Republican,Optometrist,"Rogers Public School Board,U.S. House","University of Arkansas, Fayetteville(attended)Southern College of Optometry(OD)","January 3, 2011","(1950-12-10)December 10, 1950(age 66)",2022
```